# Binary search over the chromatic number of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, median

I am developing an algorithm to find the chromatic number of a graph. I use a genetic algorithm in order to determine whether the graph can be colored using p colors. I determine p using a binary search. The lower boundary of my binary search is 1 and the upper boundary according to Brooks' theorem is the degree of the graph plus one. As I know, the possibility of a number to be the answer is not evenly distributed, thus I cannot use the middle of the interval every time. So how can I determine the median point in an optimal way?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I think that you should just tweak it to work in your setting, instead of trying to create a general algorithm. Perhaps some previous iterations of the genetic algorithm could help?

Comment: I recall that even [an approximation of the chromatic number of the graph is hard](http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2007.v003a006), so there should be no quick algorithms for it.